# NGINX multiple target ports

Tags: nginx

My application have a requirement to listen on 120 different ports and have 20 different target ports. I can see in NGINX we can allow 120 ports or more as listeners port but not finding a way to allow 30 different target ?
Has anyone experience this .

Comment: What do you mean by "target" ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182278/7121513) answer.